# What can I substitute for flour in pancakes?

Tags: substitutions, pancakes

I don't have flour to make pancakes. Are there ingredients I use as a substitute, or is there a way to make pancakes without flour?

Comment: I have seen a few "weight loss" pancake recipes around that use mashed bananas instead of flour, mixed with eggs for consistency.

Comment: Have you considered [french toast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_toast)?

Answer (score 3):

Oats can be a good substitute, just blend them and use as normal flower.

250-300g oats, two medium sized eggs, 300 ml milk and 1/2 portion bag of baking soda.

Normally I use a mix of flour and oats, so I have never tried it with oats alone but I guess if you do not have flour you can try.